# How do I get a substring between a string and the first occurrence of another string?

Tags: javascript, string

My attempt so far:

```
const myString = 'Hello my name is Barbara but i dont really like the name Barbara I prefer Barb'

const mySubString = myString.substring(
   myString.indexOf("Hello") + 6,
   myString.lastIndexOf("Barbara")
);
console.log(mySubString)
```

this returns `my name is Barbara but i dont really like the name`, but I need `my name is`.

And I don't see a `firstIndexOf()` method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `lastIndexOf` if you want the first occurrence. `indexOf` gives the index of the first occurrence.

```js
const myString = 'Hello my name is Barbara but i dont really like the name Barbara I prefer Barb'
const mySubString = myString.substring(
   myString.indexOf("Hello") + 6,
   myString.indexOf("Barbara") - 1
);
console.log('"' + mySubString + '"');
```